# Having problem in Dynamic CSS in Vue-laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Here's the template where my button and contactList1 reside:-

```
<template>
    <div class="chat-app">
    <button v-on:click="displayList1()">Contacts List 1</button>  //Button
        <Conversation :contact="selectedContact" :messages="messages" @new="saveNewMessage" v-bind:class="{conversation:conversation}" />
        <ContactsList :contacts="contacts" @selected="startConversationWith" v-bind:class="{contactsList1:contactsList1}"/>  //contactsList
       </div>
</template>
```

The object is default set to false

```
 data() {
            return {
                
                contactsList1: {
                    default: false,
                },
              
        },
```

Method:-

```
displayList1()
        {
            this.contactsList1 = false;

        },
```

Style:-

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.chat-app {
    display: flex;
}
.contactsList1 {
    background-color: black;
   
}
</style>
```

Even after the object being `false` the css is being applied, can anyone tell me what's wrong. I am just a beginner, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data function is returning the object **contactsList1** and the full path to check the data type is **this.contactsList1.default**

You should also name your variables differently.

So here is a basic example on how to bind a Boolean datatype to your component class:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      firstClass: {
        status: false
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeColour() {
      this.firstClass.status = true
    }
  }
  })
```

```css
.styleFirstClass {
  background: red
}
.itemBox {
  padding:30px;
  margin:30px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="changeColour()">Click to bind class</button>

  <div class="itemBox" :class="{styleFirstClass: firstClass.status}">
  This is some text
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a well explained answer, It worked.